# QField and streetview

Tags: qfield, google-street-view, augmented-reality

I wanted to know if anyone knows how to integrate **streetview** into **QField** or find a way to view my data in augmented reality with open source software.

Comment: That would be an interesting tool. Contact OpenGIS.ch boys to see if it is possible

Comment: But don't forget streetview is from Google and they have their licenses. In QGIS is is possible to use 
go2mapillary plugin as an alternative to streetview. And any user can contribute to mapillary